# Dump Lora.read() to array

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, lora

I want to dump chars from a Lora transmitter using Arduino Nano. With this line I assume it can be store the chars into an array:

```
char* dump = (char)LoRa.read();
char in[255];
strcpy(in, dump);
char str[] = in;
```

But unfortunately I get this compiler error:

```
exit status 1
initializer fails to determine size of 'str'
```

How I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I give my entire code. I used shox96 [shox96 from siara-cc](https://github.com/siara-cc/Shox96_Arduino_lib) for my objective to compress the data from Lora.read().

```
void print_compressed(char *in, int len) {
  int l;
  byte bit;
  //Serial.write("\nCompressed bits:");
  for (l=0; l<len*8; l++) {
    bit = (in[l/8]>>(7-l%8))&0x01;
    //Serial.print((int)bit);
    //if (l%8 == 7) Serial.print(" ");
  }
}

void loop() {
  char* dump = (char)LoRa.read();
  char in[255];
  strcpy(in, dump);
  char str[] = in;
  char cbuf[300];
  char dbuf[300];

  int len = sizeof(str);

  if (len > 0) {
    memset(cbuf, 0, sizeof(cbuf));
    int ctot = shox96_0_2_compress(str, len, cbuf, NULL);
    print_compressed(cbuf, ctot);
    memset(dbuf, 0, sizeof(dbuf));
    int dlen = shox96_0_2_decompress(cbuf, ctot, dbuf, NULL);
    dbuf[dlen] = 0;

    float perc = (dlen-ctot);
    perc /= dlen;
    perc *= 100;

    Serial.print(ctot);
    Serial.write(",");
    Serial.println(dlen);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: How many copies of this string do you need?  Now you're going to have dump, in, and str that all hold the same data.  From the looks of the size of in you expect this to be a large amount of data.  Which Arduino do you have?  How much RAM can you spend on this one string?  I think perhaps you have a larger problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Isn't `LoRa.read()` returning a single byte and not a pointer?

Comment: @Delta_G I just want to dump max. 255 byte of data, and I used Arduino Nano.

Comment: @gre_gor yes, it returns a byte. I also don't think my code is really right.

Comment: What type of Arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler can only supply the size of an array for you on creation if it has a brace enclosed initializer list.  Like this:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

If you're doing anything other than that then you need to put a number inside those braces.  Since you're making a copy of the array in and that array is 255 char then this one needs to be 255 char as well in order to accommodate.

```
char str[255] = in;
```

My comment on your question still stands though.  This answer clears your compiler error, but I don't think it is really a solution to your larger problem.  But without seeing more of your code and knowing more about it I can't tell much about it.  You already have two copies of this data by the time you get to that line.  I'm not sure why you think you need to have a third.

Comment: Thank you, yes you are right, it will be very complex problem. I will update my entire code. Perhaps there is another way to solve this.